# how remove empty space when design cut (css)

Tags: css

html:

```
<form name="search" method="post" action=" " class="search">
<input type="text" id='userInput' name="src" class="test" placeholder="Search" onKeyPress="if (event.keyCode==13){ change(this.value);return false;}">
```

css:

```
.test {
background: #000 url('../img/bg.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left;
text-indent: 17px;
color:#FFFFFF;
border: none; 
padding: 0 0 0 10px; 
top: 0;  
outline: none; 
font-size: 22px; 
position: relative; 
width: 100%; 
height: 50px;
}
```

It looks like this:
[image: http://s24.postimg.org/e0l3ak6xx/image.png]

How do I make it like this photo:
[image: http://s7.postimg.org/5pfmf041n/image.png]

I tried:

```
left:20px;
```

But when design cut (responsive design) my search form goes bellow and with `left:20px;` I have 20px of empty space, how do I remove this 20px empty space when design cut ?

Comment: Post your HTML that goes with the CSS, otherwise your question is too broad.

Comment: Can you post what you have in jsFiddle?

Comment: Add margin or padding to the search/magnifier icon

Comment: @almis can you pls add code ?

Comment: I don't know the id of your icon but e.g. `#icon {padding-left: 10px}` or  `#icon {margin-left: 10px}`

Comment: icon name is ''bg'' then will be #bg {padding-left:10px} ?

Comment: `background-position: 20px center;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `background-position: 20px center;`

```
.test {
    background: #000 url('../img/bg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 20px center;
    text-indent: 37px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    border: none; 
    padding: 0 0 0 10px; 
    top: 0;  
    outline: none; 
    font-size: 22px; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50px;
}
```